# Question regarding the equivalence of two relations in a finite group given a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a group and $H$ a finite subgroup of $G$ (i.e. $H \leq G, \lvert H \rvert = n \in \mathbb{N}^*)$. Prove the following two relations are equivalent ($e$ is the identity element):
>
> 1. $\forall x, y \in G-H, x \neq y \implies xy \neq yx;$
> 2. $(H, \cdot)$ is abelian, $\lvert G \rvert=2\lvert H \rvert, |Z(G)| = 1;$

I first assumed 2) then proved 1).

$$\begin{align*}
x \in G-H &\implies xh \in G-H, \forall h \in H.\\
 xh_1=xh_2 &\implies h_1=h_2, \forall h_1, h_2 \in H.\\\
 |G-H|=|H| &\implies G-H= \{ xh \mid h \in H \}
\end{align*}$$

Now we have
$$\begin{align*}
(xh_1)(xh_2)=(xh_2)(xh_1) &\implies h_2^{-1}h_1xh_2h_1^{-1}=e\\ &\implies (h_2^{-1}h_1)x(h_2^{-1}h_1)^{-1}=e.
\end{align*}$$
$(h_2^{-1}h_1)^{-1}=h_1^{-1}h_2=h_2h_1^{-1}$ because $(H, \cdot)$ is abelian. $gxg^{-1}=e$ has one solution, namely  $x=e$, when $g \in G$.

I did not use the fact that $Z(G)$ is trivial here and I have no idea how to prove 2) assuming 1). Is the question wrong or did I do a mistake?

Comment: Try your solution with $G=C_6$ the cyclic group of order $6$, $H=C_3$, and see if it still works. If it does, then it has to be wrong because of course this group does not satisfy (a). If it doesn't work, somewhere you used $Z(G)=1$.

Comment: I think you should not delete a post where you received a lot of comments, and create an identical one some minutes later.

Comment: $(xh_1)(xh_2)=(xh_2)(xh_1)\implies h_2^{-1}h_1xh_2h_1^{-1}=x,$ not $e.$

Comment: For future readers: the post has been edited. The (a) mentionned in @DavidA.Craven 's comment above has become 1.

Comment: Even without the mistake pointed above, I don't understand how you claimed having proved $2\implies 1.$

Comment: The two statements are not equivalent: take $G$ to be any nonabelian finite group, and take $G=H$. Then (1) is true by vacuity, but (2) is false. It is also false if $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H=\{1\}$, even though this satisfies (1).

Comment: However, $2\implies1$: using $Z(G)=\{e\},$ it is easy to repair and complete the OP's start of proof. From $(xh_1)(xh_2)=(xh_2)(xh_1)$ we deduce $h_2^{-1}h_1x=xh_1h_2^{-1}=xh_2^{-1}h_1$ and then (using that $H$ is abelian and $G=H\cup xH$) $h_2^{-1}h_1\in Z(G)$ i.e. $h_1=h_2.$

Answer (score 7):

The argument you present is incorrect, which is why you seem to not use $Z(G)=1$. Your error is in the calculations, as noted by Anne Bauval. From
$$(xh_1)(xh_2) = (xh_2)(xh_1)$$
we cancel $x$ and deduce $h_1xh_2 = h_2xh_1$, which can be written as $(h_2^{-1}h_1)x = x(h_1h_2^{-1}) = x(h_2^{-1}h_1)$ or as $(h_2^{-1}h_1)x(h_2^{-1}h_1)^{-1}=x$, using the fact that $H$ is abelian.  You have $(h_2^{-1}h_1)x(h_2^{-1}h_1)^{-1}=e$, missing the $x$ on the right hand side.

The correct calculation tells you that $h_1h_2^{-1}$ commutes with $x$, and since it lies in $H$, its centralizer contains $\langle H,x\rangle = G$. Thus, $h_1h_2^{-1}\in Z(G)=\{e\}$, which proves $h_1=h_2$. We conclude that if $x,y\in G-H$ commute, then $x=y$.

Now, the statements as written are not equivalent, since one can take $G$ to be a finite nonabelian group, and $G=H$. Then (1) is true, but (2) is not. And if $H$ is trivial and $G=\mathbb{Z}_2$, then (1) is true (since you cannot find two distinct elements of $G$), but (2) is false because $Z(G)$ is not trivial.

So let us assume that $H$ is a *proper* subgroup of $G$, that $G\neq \mathbb{Z}_2$, and $G$ satisfies (1).

Note that if $x\notin H$, then $x^{-1}\notin H$, and since $x$ commutes with its inverse, then we must have $x=x^{-1}$. Thus, every element not in $H$ is of order $2$. If $H$ is trivial, then this means that $G$ itself is abelian; and because $G$ is not $\mathbb{Z}_2$, it contains two distinct nonidentity elements, and does not satisfy (1). So this is impossible. Thus, $H$ is nontrivial.

Now, suppose that $z\in Z(G)$. If $z\in H$, then letting $x\notin H$ and looking at $xz$ and $x$, which commute, we conclude that $z=1$. And if $z\notin H$, then taking any $h\in H$ we have that $zh\notin H$ commutes with $z$, so $h=1$. Since $H$ is nontrivial, this is a contradiction. We conclude that $Z(G)=1$.

Now, $H$ is normal: if $h\in H$ and $x\notin H$, then $xh$ is of order $2$, as is $x$, so $xh=(xh)^{-1} = h^{-1}x^{-1}=h^{-1}x$, so $xhx^{-1}=h^{-1}$. Thus, $H$ is normal in $G$.

Moreover, conjugation by $x$ is an automorphism of $H$, and as noted above it corresponds to the inversion map, and so we conclude that $H$ is abelian.

It only remains to show that $|G|=2|H|$. If $x$ and $y$ are both not in $H$, and $xy\notin H$, then $xy=(xy)^{-1}=yx$, so $x=y$, and then $xy=1\in H$. Hence this is impossible. So if $x,y\notin H$, then $xy\in H$. That means that the product of any two nontrivial elements of $G/H$ is the identity, so $G/H\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. Thus, $[G:H]=2$, as desired.

Note that if you replace $|G|=2|H|$ with $[G:H]=2$, and you drop the assumption that $H$ is finite, the result still holds (once you add the additional assumptions).